# Formatting string in Java using return string.format(...)

Tags: java, string, format

Say I want to return something like this:
"Title **bookTitle**, Author **bookAuthor**: $**cost**"

The ones in bold are variables. 
I can't figure out how to return this using string.format("%s .., blah blah")

Answer (score 9):

```
String title = "bookTitle";
String author = "bookAuthor";
double cost = 100;
String text = String.format("Title %s, Author %s: $%.2f", title, author, cost);
System.out.println(text); // prints "Title bookTitle, Author bookAuthor: $100.00"
// or System.out.pritnf("Title %s, Author %s: $%.2f", title, author, cost);
```

Answer (score 5):

2 strings and a float with precision 2

```
String.format("Title %s, Author %s: $%f.2", bookTitle, bookAuthor, cost);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String fs;
fs = String.format("Title %t, Author %a: $%c", bookTitle, bookAuthor, cost);
System.out.println(fs);
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html